# How to get a DOM node, jQuery node or selector pointing to the element?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-plugins, jstree

I want to use ._get_type ( node ) function from [jsTree plugin types](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types) The documentation says

> Get the type of a node.
>            (mixed node)
>            This can be a DOM node, jQuery node or selector pointing to the element.

I do not know what to supply as a `node`. I use [hotkeys plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/hotkeys) and on enter press I want to display the type of that node.

I hope this is the relevant html code where `rel="testsuite"` specifies the node type.

```
<li class="jstree-closed" runurl="&lt;a class='non-html' href=&quot;http://10.0.0.50:4567/run2?run=login&amp;group=basics&quot;&gt;run&lt;/a&gt;" rel="testsuite" run="&lt;button class=&quot;square_button button_background&quot; type=&quot;button&quot; onclick=&quot;run_through_ajax('login','basics')&quot; &gt; run &lt;/button&gt;">
```

Is there any tutorial that can help me to understand anything I need to know my own questions like that in the future? Note that I cannot read jsTree source code in order to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not know what to supply as a `node`.

It means you can pass any of...

- `document.getElementById('abc')`
- `$('#abc')`
- `#abc`

It means it probably wraps the argument with `$()`, meaning it will automatically support all three.

Comment: how can I do in general? I mean how I pass the `abc` using some variable or something like that.